# Spring Boot Difference with Date

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

Upgraded my product from spring framework to spring boot. It is using json Parser from fasterxml.jackson. Unit tests having date comparison are failing now.

Expected time is

`2098-12-31T00:00:00.000Z`

but actual is

`2098-12-30T15:00:00.000Z`

My locale is Asia/Tokyo. I tried to change timezone in the mapper, currently showing Asia/Tokyo, to UTC but did not work.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: can you show the code. There can be more than one places where the config is not correct anymore

Comment: It has xml insert, libraries and dependencies, it is difficult to share code. Debugging jackson library, thank you

Comment: One way to fix assertion is by checking against time in long value as time date.getTime() this gives long value which is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library I was using fasterxml.jackson 2.8.3 was not spring boot compatible. Not sure why though. I used another json parser and solve